# UIScrollView scrollable area not updating with scrollView frame constraint update

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I'm updating a frame constraint

```
scrollView.top Equal container.top
```

by subtracting from the constant, then calling layoutIfNeeded()

The scrollview's frame updates fine, and the content comes with it, but in the new area that the scrollview has acquired (above the scrollview) it does not fire scroll events when dragging.  The old area works.

I've tried updating the contentOffset, but that effectively scrolls the content up inside the scrollview instead of expanding the scrollable area

I'm updating the contentSize, but it seems like problem is where the contentSize starts from

I've tried updating the contentInset, that still just moves the content around without updating the scrollable area

Maybe there is a property that needs to be updated but I can't find it

The end goal here is to programmatically increase the size of a scrollView

here is scrollViewDidScroll, where I'm updating the constraint

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let newVal:CGFloat = -120.0
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        self.feedTableViewTopConstraint.constant = newVal
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
setNeedsLayout()
```

instead and if you want the  layoutIfNeeded() to happen in the same loop then you can call it immediately after you called setNeedsLayout()